# Why does gradle break my type-ahead (Windows)?

Tags: windows, gradle, command-line

This applies to the windows version of Gradle 4.8.1

When I'm executing a gradle script it consumes my keystrokes from stdin.  This seems completely unnecessary.  Groovy doesn't require this and gradle doesn't seem to use the keystrokes for anything, but it stops you from issuing the next command during a build.

Is there some magic hidden keyboard command that works during builds?  Is there a command line mode that activates even when it's unused.

I've never seen another program that did this, even ones that can use stdin don't just open it, leave it open then throw away the input!

I'd appreciate a way to shut it off, but I'd totally settle for some logical reason.